# Remove duplicates from a list in CF10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have the following string but before I use this string, I want to remove the duplicates from it:

```
http://website.com/abc.asp?type=298&action=SUBMIT&product=&contribution=&rateTerm=&surrYr=&mva=&rop=&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2&pagenum=3&company=&product=&state=&contribution=&rateTerm=&surrYr=&mva=&rop=
```

I tried using the **cflib** Function [listRemoveDuplicates](http://www.cflib.org/udf/ListRemoveDuplicates), but that does not seem to solve the issue.

It should look like:

```
http://website.com/abc.asp?type=298&action=SUBMIT&product=&contribution=&rateTerm=&surrYr=&mva=&rop=&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2&pagenum=3
```

I am using cf10.

Comment: What do you expect the finished string to look like?  Can you show us how you're calling the function?  Which version of CF are you on; you might be able to use the native [ListRemoveDuplicates](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListRemoveDuplicates) function if CF 10 or above

Comment: What is the expected output compared to the actual output in what you are trying to do? Show us the code you have used.

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in ListRemoveDuplicates function in CF10?

Comment: *but that does not seem to solve the issue* That is a bit vague :) You need to show us the code you tried and explain how the results differ from what you expected. Only include the code required to [reproduce the issue](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: In your expected output, you have removed `company=&state=` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cfoutput you are expecting should have `company=&state=` as well. As they are distinct too. So taking this in account you can give this a try:

```
<cfset url = "http://website.com/abc.asp?type=298&action=SUBMIT&product=&contribution=&rateTerm=&surrYr=&mva=&rop=&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2&pagenum=3&company=&product=&state=&contribution=&rateTerm=&surrYr=&mva=&rop=">

<!--- Get domain name and query string --->
<cfset domainName = listGetAt(url , 1, "?")>
<cfset queryString = listGetAt(url , 2, "?")>
<cfset tempStruct = structNew()>
<cfloop list="#queryString#" index="currentString" delimiters="&">
    <cfset tempStruct[ currentString ] = "">
</cfloop>
<cfset queryString = structKeyList(tempStruct,"&")>
<cfset newUrl = domainName & "?" & queryString>
```

**Output**:

```
http://website.com/abc.asp?rateTerm=&company=&mva=&pagenum=3&sortOrder=2&product=&rop=&action=SUBMIT&state=&type=298&surrYr=&contribution=&sortBy=1
```

And to preserve the order you can define the `tempStruct` like this:

```
<cfset tempStruct = structNew()>
<cfset tempStruct = createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init() />
```

**Output**:

```
http://website.com/abc.asp?type=298&action=SUBMIT&product=&contribution=&rateTerm=&surrYr=&mva=&rop=&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2&pagenum=3&company=&state=
```

As you are using `CF10` then you can use [ListRemoveDuplicates](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListRemoveDuplicates) also like this:

```
<cfset url = "http://website.com/abc.asp?type=298&action=SUBMIT&product=&contribution=&rateTerm=&surrYr=&mva=&rop=&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2&pagenum=3&company=&product=&state=&contribution=&rateTerm=&surrYr=&mva=&rop=">

<!--- Get domain name and query string --->
<cfset domainName = listGetAt(url , 1, "?")>
<cfset queryString = listGetAt(url , 2, "?")>
<cfset queryString = listRemoveDuplicates(queryString, "&")>
<cfset newUrl = domainName & "?" & queryString>
```

**Output**:

```
http://website.com/abc.asp?type=298&action=SUBMIT&product=&contribution=&rateTerm=&surrYr=&mva=&rop=&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2&pagenum=3&company=&state=
```